# How to make Looney-Tune style eyelids

Tags: modeling, animation

I'm kinda stuck. I have this character and I'm almost done modeling him, but I want him to have eyelids/eyebrows like Daffy Duck or Bugs Bunny. I tried Making an M-shaped arch out of a cube but it looked ugly, i tried duplicating the eyes, cutting them in half, and positioning them to where I can use shape keys to make them come down over the eye, but I lost confidence in that idea so I quit trying. I even tried using sculpting tools but I never have good luck with those. If anybody knows how to achieve this look and make them come down in a blinking fashion that'd be great[image]

Comment: could you please show your attempts and maybe share your file? Also, do you want the eyebrows to be part of the head mesh?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest is probably to create some separate meshes for the eyebrows and the eyelids, something like that:

[image]

A test of rigging for the eyelid:

[image]

Comment: That's really smart! I'm gonna try that